# LockBits image rotation method not working?

Tags: c#, gdi+, bitmap, lockbits

Hey all. I resorted to using LockBits for 2d bitmap image rotation after getting fed up with the slow performance and wacky behavior of both Get/Set Pixel, and RotateTransfom. So here is the code I've come up with, and by my reckoning, it should work perfectly. It doesn't.

```
private static void InternalRotateImage(Bitmap originalBitmap, Bitmap rotatedBitmap, PointF centerPoint, float theta)
    {
        BitmapData originalData = originalBitmap.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, originalBitmap.Width, originalBitmap.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
            originalBitmap.PixelFormat);

        BitmapData rotatedData = rotatedBitmap.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, rotatedBitmap.Width, rotatedBitmap.Height),
            ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
            rotatedBitmap.PixelFormat);

        unsafe
        {
            byte[,] A = new byte[originalData.Height * 2, originalBitmap.Width * 2];
            byte[,] R = new byte[originalData.Height * 2, originalBitmap.Width * 2];
            byte[,] G = new byte[originalData.Height * 2, originalBitmap.Width * 2];
            byte[,] B = new byte[originalData.Height * 2, originalBitmap.Width * 2];

            for (int y = 0; y < originalData.Height; y++)
            {
                byte* row = (byte*)originalData.Scan0 + (y * originalData.Stride);
                for (int x = 0; x < originalData.Width; x++)
                {
                    B[y, x] = row[x * 4];
                    G[y, x] = row[x * 4 + 1];
                    R[y, x] = row[x * 4 + 2];
                    A[y, x] = row[x * 4 + 3];
                }
            }

            for (int y = 0; y < rotatedData.Height; y++)
            {
                byte* row = (byte*)rotatedData.Scan0 + (y * rotatedData.Stride);
                for (int x = 0; x < rotatedData.Width; x++)
                {
                    int newy = (int)Math.Abs((Math.Cos(theta) * (x - centerPoint.X) - Math.Sin(theta) * (y - centerPoint.Y) + centerPoint.X));
                    int newx = (int)Math.Abs((Math.Sin(theta) * (x - centerPoint.X) + Math.Cos(theta) * (y - centerPoint.Y) + centerPoint.Y));

                    row[x * 4] = B[newy, newx];
                    row[x * 4 + 1] = G[newy, newx];
                    row[x * 4 + 2] = R[newy, newx];
                    row[x * 4 + 3] = A[newy, newx];
                }
            }

        }
            originalBitmap.UnlockBits(originalData);
            rotatedBitmap.UnlockBits(rotatedData);
        }
```

Anybody got any ideas? I'm fresh out. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
This is what I ended up using (many thanks to Hans Passant):

```
private Image RotateImage(Image img, float rotationAngle)
    {
        Image image = new Bitmap(img.Width * 2, img.Height * 2);
        Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(image);

        int center = (int)Math.Sqrt(img.Width * img.Width + img.Height * img.Height) / 2;
        gfx.TranslateTransform(center, center);
        gfx.RotateTransform(rotationAngle);
        gfx.DrawImage(img, -img.Width / 2, -img.Height / 2);

        return image;
    }
```

It's the same thing as his, just on a per image basis, as opposed to a form.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the four `byte[,] A = new byte[...` lines?  I don't understand why you're creating a two-dimensional byte array where one dimension is twice the original bitmap's height and the second dimension is the height times the width.

Comment: Sorry, the height width one was an old edit. I edited it to reflect whats correct... And I times them both by 2 in order to make sure they can handle of ranges of the rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are digging yourself a deeper hole.  This goes wrong early, the size of the rotated bitmap is not Width x Height.  It is also very inefficient.  You need to get RotateTransform going, it is important to also use TranslateTransform and pick the correct image drawing location.

Here's a sample Windows Forms app that rotates a bitmap around its center point, offset just enough to touch the inner edge of the form when it rotates.  Drop a Timer on the form and add an image resource with Project + Properties, Resource tab.  Name it SampleImage, it doesn't have to be square.  Make the code look like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    private float mDegrees;
    private Image mBmp;
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        mBmp = Properties.Resources.SampleImage;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Interval = 50;
        timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        mDegrees += 3.0F;
        this.Invalidate();
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        int center = (int)Math.Sqrt(mBmp.Width * mBmp.Width + mBmp.Height * mBmp.Height) / 2;
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(center, center);
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(mDegrees);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(mBmp, -mBmp.Width/2, -mBmp.Height/2);
    }
}
```

You can make draw a lot faster by creating a bitmap in the 32bppPArgb format, I skipped that step.

Comment: Is it just me, or does the 1st row and column get screwed up during the rotate? In my case, I fixed it with empty pixels for them, and just set my image to be one pixel larger than I needed.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  You many need to round up *center* if the image size is divisible by two.  Only an odd sized bitmap has a perfect center pixel.  Or use the overloads of these methods that take float.

Comment: @ Hans: With any picture, the 1st row and column are distorted. Look at it for yourself...