# rotating a picture continuously on a windows form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, picturebox

I am trying to use the combination of the timer class and a codeproject to rotate an image smoothly in a picture box control (Visual Studio 2010 C#).  The problem I am having is either the picture doesn't rotate or I get a threading exception.  Something about "the object is in use elsewhere".  Here's the main parts of the code, I would greatly appreciate any help you can provide.  Thank you.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image); 
        //graphic.RotateTransform(45); 


        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { RotateImage(pictureBox1.Image, 10); }));    

    }



    public static Bitmap RotateImage(Image image, float angle)
    {
        // center of the image
        float rotateAtX = image.Width / 2;
        float rotateAtY = image.Height / 2;
        bool bNoClip = false;
        return RotateImage(image, rotateAtX, rotateAtY, angle, bNoClip);
    }

    public static Bitmap RotateImage(Image image, float angle, bool bNoClip)
    {
        // center of the image
        float rotateAtX = image.Width / 2;
        float rotateAtY = image.Height / 2;
        return RotateImage(image, rotateAtX, rotateAtY, angle, bNoClip);
    }

    public static Bitmap RotateImage(Image image, float rotateAtX, float rotateAtY, float angle, bool bNoClip)
    {
        int W, H, X, Y;
        if (bNoClip)
        {
            double dW = (double)image.Width;
            double dH = (double)image.Height;

            double degrees = Math.Abs(angle);
            if (degrees <= 90)
            {
                double radians = 0.0174532925 * degrees;
                double dSin = Math.Sin(radians);
                double dCos = Math.Cos(radians);
                W = (int)(dH * dSin + dW * dCos);
                H = (int)(dW * dSin + dH * dCos);
                X = (W - image.Width) / 2;
                Y = (H - image.Height) / 2;
            }
            else
            {
                degrees -= 90;
                double radians = 0.0174532925 * degrees;
                double dSin = Math.Sin(radians);
                double dCos = Math.Cos(radians);
                W = (int)(dW * dSin + dH * dCos);
                H = (int)(dH * dSin + dW * dCos);
                X = (W - image.Width) / 2;
                Y = (H - image.Height) / 2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            W = image.Width;
            H = image.Height;
            X = 0;
            Y = 0;
        }

        //create a new empty bitmap to hold rotated image
        Bitmap bmpRet = new Bitmap(W, H);
        bmpRet.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

        //make a graphics object from the empty bitmap
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpRet);

        //Put the rotation point in the "center" of the image
        g.TranslateTransform(rotateAtX + X, rotateAtY + Y);

        //rotate the image
        g.RotateTransform(angle);

        //move the image back
        g.TranslateTransform(-rotateAtX - X, -rotateAtY - Y);

        //draw passed in image onto graphics object
        g.DrawImage(image, new PointF(0 + X, 0 + Y));

        return bmpRet;
    }
```

Comment: Could it be that probably you need to reassing the returned bitmap to the pictureBox1.Image property to see the changes?

Comment: That might be the problem, I do pictureBox1.Image = bmpRet; in the method but it says it has a problem with object reference

Comment: possible duplicate of [LockBits image rotation method not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860030/lockbits-image-rotation-method-not-working)

Comment: Well i got it working, but the problem now is that the image gets blurrier and blurrier over time until you cant even tell what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should invalidate and paint in you OnPaint or OnDraw event

```
private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image); 
    //graphic.RotateTransform(45); 


   // this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { RotateImage(pictureBox1.Image, 10); }));    

    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

In your form you should enable this styles for a better perfomance and smoothness

```
SetStyle( ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true );
SetStyle( ControlStyles.UserPaint, true );
SetStyle( ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true );
SetStyle( ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true );
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped.  But I can't believe i forgot to reassign the returned bitmap image to the picture box's image!