# How can change center rotation using C# Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, rotation

How can I create a Center of Rotation in Winforms?

What I mean is when I look over the web I found some guides that had a radius for the rotation so it created some circle movement, however I want Only to rotate an image over a certain point without any radius rotation.
How can I do something like that?

Comment: Hard to guess what "radius rotation" might mean.  In general you have to use Graphics.TranslateTransform() to rotate around a point other than (0, 0).  Check this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3860678/17034

Comment: That's Exactly what I mean Thanks a lot :)